# Certain applications (e.g. Adobe Acrobat) don't display properly on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, display, adobe-acrobat

I have had a problem recently and wanted to see if anyone else had a similar problem or solution.

I am using Windows XP (with all the latest updates).  Every time I restart the computer, it runs perfectly.  But after some period of usage (I haven't figured out a pattern), certain applications (most obviously Adobe Acrobat) don't display properly.  When I have a pdf open and maximized, it just shows as a blank screen.  But when I shrink the application so that it only takes up a small part of the screen (~20%), then the document will display.

Any ideas?  Is there some application in the task manager that I can restart when this happens to reset the drivers or something like that?

Comment: Are you running multiple monitors?

Comment: @JNK: Yes, although this happens even when I only have one monitor active.

Comment: OK there is a related thread [here](http://superuser.com/questions/185642/application-screen-repainting-issues)

Comment: Thanks @JNK: I changed my monitor settings based on that thread and we'll see if it helps.  If you post that as an answer, I'll give you an up-vote and accept if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the suggestions in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/185642/application-screen-repainting-issues).

Similar situation, though not exactly the same.

Comment: This seems to have worked!  Changed some nVidia settings.

Comment: @Shane - good to hear!  We like it when things get fixed.